# java.net.MalformedURLException trying to retrieve a photo saved on my Android device

Tags: java, android, malformedurlexception

I am trying to add in my App a function to use the camera to store photos in my device.
At the beginning i use the camera like this:

```
        mButtonCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count++;
                String file = dir+prova+".jpg";
                File newFile = new File(file);
                try {
                    newFile.createNewFile();
                }catch (IOException e){}

                Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newFile);

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,outputFileUri);
                Log.v("CameraDemo", "Pic savedNO");
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
            }
        });
```

And then for the OnActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.v("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");
        Log.v("Salva Foto", dir+prova+".jpg");
        myDBHandler.addPhoto(prova,dir+prova+".jpg");

    }
}
```

Until here evrything is ok but when I try to retrieve the photo using this:

```
        InputStream URLcontent = null;
        try {
            URLcontent = (InputStream) new URL(fotoSI).getContent();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Drawable image = Drawable.createFromStream(URLcontent, fotoSI);
        mImageCamera.setImageDrawable(image);
```

It doesn´t return any photo that is what the Log says me:

java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/

I am trying everything but without results.

Comment: URLcontent is null. Are you sure you want to keep it null?

Comment: :), Malformed URL means, what you supplied is not an URL, see the error above, it says::: java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/ ::: You are trying to load a relative file system as URL it will not work try the file URL form 'file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/'

Comment: Thank you very much IronLuca.Yes you are right adding "file://" at the beginning of the path just solved my problem!Thank you thank you thank you!